# Calling PowerShell scripts from unmanaged C++

Tags: c++, windows, powershell

Microsoft appears to be moving a lot of configuration and query capabilities to PowerShell (accessible from C# or managed C++), while deprecating and even removing older APIs (accessible for C or unmanaged C++). Those of us who have extensive unmanaged C++ programs that can't switch to managed C++ may have a need to call PowerShell cmdlets (at least, I have one now) -- how can we do so?

There are suggestions that a reverse-PInvoke (managed/unmanaged thunking) might be able to do something, but I'm hoping for a better way than either thunking or parsing text output from a PowerShell script.

[Note: This is a reworked and generalized [query I made yesterday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/489023/querying-exchange-2007-storage-group-database-details-with-unmanaged-c) that may have been too specialized.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MS suggestion would probably be to compile specific classes/modules in your generally unmanaged C++ app as managed code (compiling individual files with /clr), and letting the IJW transition code manage the calls to/from it (and calling PowerShell API's from the managed bits). I've been told (from MS VC++ people) that's the expected methodology for adding bits of managed calls to large unmanaged applications.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks. This suggestion gave me some interesting things to query, and we have a planned implementation based on what we found.